# Pagetable nomenclature

Tags: x86, operating-system, virtual-memory, systems-programming, page-tables

While researching virtual memory, I sometimes see conflicting use of the nouns *page table*, *page table entry*, and *page*. For example "A page table is a table of pages..." and "A page table holds page table entries".

My understanding of the relationships (in the context of x86-64) are as follows:

- Virtual memory is divided into blocks (i.e. pages)
- A page table is an array of entries

  - There is one entry per page
  - Each entry is an address composed of metadata

    - Permission bits
    - In a direct mapping, a physical address to a frame
    - Or, a physical address to another other page tables

Is this high-level summary, and use of the aforementioned nouns, accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this high-level summary, and use of the aforementioned nouns, accurate?

Not quite (none of the entries ever contain virtual addresses). For "plain 32-bit paging" on 80x86 (2 levels):

- A page directory is an array of page directory entries

  - A page directory entry contains the physical address of a page table, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)
- A page table is an array of page table entries

  - A page table entry contains the physical address of a page, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)

For "long mode paging" on 80x86 (4 levels):

- A PML4 (Page Map Level 4) is an array of PML4 entries

  - A PML4 entry contains the physical address of a page, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)
- A PDPT (Page Directory Pointer Table) is an array of PDPT entries

  - A PDPT entry contains the physical address of a page directory, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)
- A page directory is an array of page directory entries

  - A page directory entry contains the physical address of a page table, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)
- A page table is an array of page table entries

  - A page table entry contains the physical address of a page, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)

Of course there's a pattern here:

- A `<NAME>` is an array of `<NAME>` entries

  - A `<NAME>` entry contains the physical address of a `<NEXT_LOWER_LEVEL_NAME>`, with some bits (that would've been zero) re-purposed for various flags (e.g. permission bits)

.. where "`<NAME>`" is (from highest to lowest) one of: `PML5`, `PML4`, `Page Directory Pointer Table`, `Page Directory`, `Page Table`.